# Executing raw sql queries with rails Active record methods

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a situation like finding the persons who matches the filter applied. For that I have constructed query(select ids of people who matches filter condition) for persons who matches the filter. and then get the person details for the filtered people.

```
 m = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(filter_blocks_query.join(' INTERSECT ')) unless  filter_blocks_query.empty?
Person.where(id: m.rows.flatten)
```

But this executes the result and then filters people who matches the filtered IDs. Is there any ways to make it like a single query.
`filter_blocks_query` is raw sql statement.

Comment: Hard to say much without knowing what is in `filter_blocks_query` but I think you're looking for `Person.find_by_sql(filter_blocks_query_something)` and then modify the SQL in `filter_blocks_query` to include `select * from people` to get the right columns.

Comment: Filter_blocks query is something like `((SELECT "people"."id" FROM "people" WHERE "people"."project_id" = 2 AND (email IS NOT NULL) AND (people.id NOT IN (325122,325163,325164)) GROUP BY people.id))`

Comment: So change them to `select * from people ...`, drop the GROUP BYs, and use `find_by_sql`.